# How can I implement Sign Up/Login logic with Provider. Flutter, Dart, Mobile Development

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, provider, flutter-change-notifier

Let' say I have three files: **main.dart**, **LoginScreen.dart**, **HomePageScreen.dart**. I am utilizing **Provider** architecture for state management and wrapping MaterialApp.

When the app startup, the main.dart file checks whether the user is already Logged in (FirebaseAuth.currentUser to check this). If it is logged in, navigate to HomePageScreen, if not then navigate to SignUpScreen. Something like this on code:

```
// Inside of main
AppUser user = await database.getCurrentUser(); // user == null if no fbAuth.currentUser
runApp(MultiProvider(
    providers: [,
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => user),
      // some other notifier providers,
    ],
    child: MyApp(),
  ));



// Inside of MyApp
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
      ...
      home: user == null ? SignupScreen() : HomePageScreen();
   );
}
```

This is great, it is working as I expected. If currentUser is null, it navigates to SignupScreen, if not then to HomePageScreen.

### Problem:

In HomepageScreen, it listens to the User provider and updates UI components accordingly. Therefore, when the user successfully signed up for a new account or log in, I want to change/update the content of the user in the provider, so that when the app screen shift from SignupScreen to HomePageScreen, it displays the correct information on HomePageScreen. However, I cannot find a way to change the reference of the user inside of the provider.

### Things that I tried:

In AppUser.dart, I created the method for changing the user reference:

```
class AppUser with ChangeNotifier {
   String username, email, password;
   
   void changeReference(AppUser newlyCreatedUser) {
      this.username = newlyCreatedUser.username;
      this.password = newlyCreatedUser.password;
      this.email = newlyCreatedUser.email;
   }
}
```

This is really just changing the content of the user. This way I can update the user to a newly created user. However, my instinct tells me that this is a very bad way of solving this problem. I feel like the problem is laying in the logic, the way I am trying to implement the sign up/login feature.

### Summary:

Is there a way to change the reference of the value in the provider?
If this is not possible, or a bad way of using provider architecture, do you have any suggestion of how to implement Sign up feature